# How to build where predicate in EF Core in which the property selected is dynamic

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, npgsql

I'm struggling with expression trees and Entity Framework Core.

I have a method that returns an expression tree that I will use for filtering, something like:

```
public Expression<Func<E, bool>> GetWherePredicate<E>(Func<E, NpgsqlTsVector> selector, string queryText) 
{
    return entity => selector(entity).Matches(queryText);
}
```

And then I'd like to invoke this method with something like:

```
 query = query.Where(GetWherePredicate<MyEntity>(i => i.MySearchField, "the_query"));
```

This produces an error, something like:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(i => Invoke(__selector_0, i)
> .Matches(__queryText_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

While I understand why this doesn't work, I am not sure how to solve this, but suspect it has to do with using expression trees. I thought of creating a new function that has the following signature, something like:

```
Expression<Func<E, bool>> GetWherePredicate<E>(MemberExpression selectorForSearchField, string queryText);
```

But I am not able to figure out how to take that expression and apply the `Matches` function.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Look at `EF.Functions.ToTsVector` method.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a way to answer the question, but it is not as simple as I would like.  Or more correctly, my intuition tells me there is a cleaner and simpler approach.

My (not so simple) approach is the following:

Create a function that takes a MemberExpression (not a function which selects the property) that looks something like the following:

```
    public Expression<Func<E, bool>> GetWherePredicate<E>(
        MemberExpression member, 
        string queryText)
    {
        // Get the parameter from the member
        var parameter = GetParameterExpression(member);

        // Convert the query text into a constant expression
        var queryTextExpression = Expression.Constant(queryText, typeof(string));

        // Create an expression for the matches function
        ftsMatchesFunction = typeof(NpgsqlFullTextSearchLinqExtensions).GetMethod("Matches",
                    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null,
                    new[] { typeof(NpgsqlTsVector), typeof(NpgsqlTsQuery) },
                    null);
        var matchesExpression = Expression.Call(ftsMatchesFunction, member, partialSearchExpression);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(matchesExpression, parameter);
    }
```

And then to add the predicate, I have something like:

```
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<MyEntity>(false);

        var myEntity= Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity), "e");
        var childEntity= Expression.PropertyOrField(myEntity, nameof(Invoice.Child));
        var searchProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(childEntity, nameof(Child.FtsSearchVector));

        predicate = predicate.Or(_context.GetWherePredicate<MyEntity>(
            searchProperty, 
            "the_query_text"));
```

And finally to add the filter to the query:

```
    query = query.Where(predicate);
```

The cleaner or simpler solution is one in which does not need Expression Trees, as the only reason expression trees are needed is because I am not able to figure out how to select the search property in a way that ef can understand.

Answer (score 0):

how to use the predicate to create an expression for retrieving objects from a list.

Method 1

Use the Predicate<generic> type and IEnumerable

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestPredicate()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product {ProductID=1,Name="Kayak",Category="Watersports",Price=275m},
                new Product {ProductID=2,Name="Lifejacket", Category="Watersports",Price=48.95m},
                new Product {ProductID=3,Name="Soccer Ball", Category="Soccer",Price=19.50m},
                new Product {ProductID=4,Name="Corner Flag", Category="Soccer",Price=34.95m}
            };

            Predicate<Product> predicate = x => x.ProductID==4;

            var query=Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(products,x=>predicate(x));

            if (query != null) { 
                output.WriteLine(query.Name);
                Assert.True(true);
            }

        }
```

Method 2

use Expression<Func pattern for your predicate:

```
Expression<Func<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn, bool>> predicate = e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId;

PageListViewContainer<TimeAndAttendancePunchInView> container = await taMod.TimeAndAttendance.Query().GetViewsByPage(predicate, order, pageSize, pageNumber);

     public async Task<PageListViewContainer<TimeAndAttendancePunchInView>>  GetViewsByPage(Expression<Func<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn, object>> order, int pageSize, int pageNumber)
    {

        var query = _unitOfWork.timeAndAttendanceRepository.GetEntitiesByExpression(predicate);
        query = query.OrderByDescending(order).Select(e => e);

        IPagedList<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn> list = await query.ToPagedListAsync(pageNumber, pageSize);
```

repository

```
 public IQueryable<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn> GetEntitiesByExpression(Expression<Func<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var result =  _dbContext.Set<TimeAndAttendancePunchIn>().Where(predicate);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Golden Lion, thanks for your response.  The problem I am having is to pass in the property selector (in your case, e.EmployeeId) to the code which builds the predicate, in a way that works with ef being able to construct the query.  I have posted an answer which I am not happy about, but maybe that can give a better sense of what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can use the Predicate generic and runtime compiling with Enumerable

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.  Does it involve runtime compiling on:
    return entity => selector(entity).Matches(queryText);

Comment: I show to ways to deal with the predicate.  The first way is directly and the second way is using an expression.   with expressions you have to get the typing correct for the predicate to return.  try returning a predicate from your function rather than an expression

Comment: if you create a predicate then you use Enumerable.FirstOrDefault to evaluate it.

Comment: Golden Lion, thanks for your help but apologies if I am missing what you are saying, but I don't think it's solving the specific issue I am trying to solve, namely being able to have LINQ translate something like:  "entity => selector(entity).Matches(queryText);" into a valid query.  In your code, I don't see an example where the queried property is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Method 1 uses a predicate instead of an expression to pass the filter criteria

Comment: In Method 1, the entire filter criteria is being passed.  What I want to pass is only the member not the entire filter, if that makes sense.  I am currently passing the member via the parameter: Func<E, NpgsqlTsVector> selector.

Comment: It seems like var matchesExpression = Expression.Call(ftsMatchesFunction, member, partialSearchExpression);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<E, bool>>(matchesExpression, parameter); will work